# Xcode documentation comment syntax

Tags: xcode, headerdoc

I was wondering if someone could explain what/if there is any difference between the following two comment syntax in Xcode.

```
/**
 * comments
 */

/*!
 * comments
 */
```

It seems like both allow Xcode to display your comments as documentation but I'm not sure if there is a difference between the two.

Comment: It matters if there is a difference between the two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent.  `/*!` is a [HeaderDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/tags/tags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001215-CH346-CHDJFEGF) style opener and `/**` is a [JavaDoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#format) style opener commonly used by [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html).  Xcode 5 supports both HeaderDoc and doxygen/JavaDoc formats.

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent by functionality.

**Differences:**

#### /**

1. Doxygen style
2. If you use `headerdoc2html` command, the `/**` based comments won't be present in the documentation file, it'll skip those comments (Refer [HeaderDoc not generating HTML Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628803/headerdoc-not-generating-html-documentation/27629007#27629007))

#### /*!

1. HeaderDoc style
2. If you use `headerdoc2html` command the `/*!` comments will be displayed on the documentation file in HTML format unlike /**