# HeaderDoc not generating HTML Documentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, documentation-generation, headerdoc

I'm working on a re-usable API component for iOS apps. I have completed the API and documented it using `headerdoc` for future users.

Now I want to create HTML pages for those header files. So I executed the following command in terminal  from my project directory

```
headerdoc2html -o ~/Desktop/My_Project_Documentation APIFolder/
```

But No documents are being created, instead I'm getting an error like:

```
Skipping. No HeaderDoc comments found.
No default encoding.  Guessing.  If date formats are wrong, try
specifying an appropriate value in the LANG environment variable.
...done
```

I tried various methods and ways, finally I narrow down the issue:

In the beginning of my project I have something like:

```
/**
 *  DarkPantherConstants.h
 *  Panther
 *  Created by Midhun on 05/11/14.
 *  Copyright (c) 2014 Midhun. All rights reserved.
 *  Panther Constants are defined in this header file
 */
```

So the issue was with this particular comment, actually this comment is auto-generated by XCode and I actually modified the name and comment format to `headerdoc`. Nothing with date or date-format. Even If I remove those comments, nothing works; getting same error. Can anybody please help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed it by changing my commenting format from:

```
/**
 *
 */
```

to

```
/*!
 *
 */
```

I made my header comment like:

```
/*!
 *  DarkPantherConstants.h
 *  Panther
 *  Created by Midhun on 05/11/14.
 *  Copyright (c) 2014 Midhun. All rights reserved.
 *  Panther Constants are defined in this header file
 */
```

And it solved the issue, but I don't know why the previous commenting format not working. (Both are valid for headerdoc)

Answer (score 7):

Add the -j options when executing headerdoc2html to also process java style comments ( /** )